# Lan speed of Airport time capsule is too slow

Tags: airport

It is a latest model of airport time capsule, the lan speed is quite slow, the speed from macbook to airport disk is 20~25MB. And the speed between the connected macbook and another client is 8~12MB. 
Both the connections are 802.11ac，and Tx rates both are 300~800MB.

Comment: Could anyone test the wifi lan speed? How fine could it be ?

Comment: The Tx rate of the connection is not the determining factor for speed here.     It is the media (whatever is in the time capsule that stores your stuff, almost certainly at least an order of magnitude slower than the connection.)